# Multiplicación de Double incorrecto

Tags: java, double

Tengo el siguiente problema, obtengo el importe como un String, necesito pasarlo a céntimos y al multiplicar por 100 obtengo un valor incorrecto al inicial, lo redondea.
¿Por qué ocurre esto y cuál sería la forma más elegante de evitarlo?

Ejemplo:

`String importe = "315.84";`

`Double importeVal = Double.valueOf(importe);` <-- Aquí se obtiene bien el valor 315.84

`importeVal = importeVal * 100;` <-- Aquí obtenemos el valor 31583.999999999996

`importe = String.valueOf(importeVal);`  <- Se convierte a string el valor 31583.999999999996

`System.out.println(importe);` <-- Se pinta 31583.999999999996

Comment: Para trabajar con dinero usa siempre BigDecimal o directamente enteros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que surge es que al realizar el cambio de un tipo a otro, parece que Java redondea. Para solucionarlo, podemos aplicar un `Math.round()` y así logramos guardar en un `long` el valor que realmente se ajusta a lo que buscas:

```
    String importe = "315.84";

    Double importeVal = Double.valueOf( importe ).doubleValue();

    long importeValRounded = Math.round( importeVal * 100 );

    importe = String.valueOf( importeValRounded );

    System.out.println( importe );
```

En este post de SO explican el problema que te ha surgido a nivel más técnico: [Double multiplied by 100 and then cast to long is giving wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467849/double-multiplied-by-100-and-then-cast-to-long-is-giving-wrong-value)